# Проблема с middleware_handler в модуле pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Никак не могу решить проблему, код не запускается

**Код:**

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("my_token")

telebot.apihelper.ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE = True
@bot.middleware_handler()
def middleware_handler(bot_instance, package):
    pass
```

**Ошибка:**

> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'default_middleware_handlers'

Traceback ошибки:

> ! Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Grig/Desktop/fast.py", line 7, in 
> def middleware_handler(bot_instance, package):
> File "C:\Users\Grig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init*_.py", line 1834, in decorator
> self.add_middleware_handler(handler, update_types)
> File "C:\Users\Grig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot_*init*_.py", line 1851, in add_middleware_handler
> self.typed_middleware_handlers[update_type].append(handler)
> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'typed_middleware_handlers'

**Pip freeze:**

> certifi==2020.12.5
> chardet==4.0.0
> idna==2.10
> pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.7
> requests==2.25.1
> six==1.15.0
> urllib3==1.26.4

**Как пытался решить проблему:**

- У меня сразу была установлена верная библиотека [pytelegrambotapi](/questions/tagged/pytelegrambotapi), но я все равно удалил все установленные пакеты и поставил библиотеку по новой
- Ставил другую версию [pytelegrambotapi](/questions/tagged/pytelegrambotapi): 
  pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI==2.2.3
- Ставил последовательно две версии [pytelegrambotapi](/questions/tagged/pytelegrambotapi):
  pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI==2.2.3
  pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI==3.6.7
- Также я переустановил питон на всякий случай, и повторил все те же действия

---

Еще пример ошибки, который возможно поможет прояснить ситуацию:

```
@bot.middleware_handler(update_types=['message', 'callback_query'])
def middleware_handler(bot_instance, package):
    pass
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'typed_middleware_handlers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решено.** Проблема была в том что *apihelper* нужно настраиваться до создания объекта *telebot*

**Корректный код:**

```
import telebot

telebot.apihelper.ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE = True
bot = telebot.TeleBot("my_token")

@bot.middleware_handler()
def middleware_handler(bot_instance, package):
    pass
```